# What is the "+" in "drwxrwsr-x+"

Tags: linux, permissions, capistrano, coreutils

I'm working a website we maintain, and I use Capistrano to deploy. I've kind of inherited the stuff, so I'm not the one who set everything up.

When I deploy to the server, it fails and nothing is updated. Since file permissions usually are the culprit of it failing, in my experience, I checked them for the folder I'm deploying to, and I saw something I haven't seen before: `drwxrwsr-x+`.

I don't know what that ending plus sign is or what it does; I assumed it was CentOS' way of denoting sticky bit, but when I ran `sudo chmod -t shared`, it was still there, so I guess it must not be the sticky bit.

Can someone who knows more about Linux tell me what the ending "+" is in that list of permissions?

Comment: It means additional permissions are available as an ACL. See [this question][1] too.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/198758/what-does-the-mean-in-the-acl-output-of-ls-l

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From `info ls`, under the [`What information is listed?`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#index-g_t_002dl-768) section, regarding the output produced by `-l`:

> ```
>  A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
>  marked with a '+' character.
> ```

Generally, it means it has an ACL set.

Comment: If I could +2, I would, because not only did that answer my question, I also had never heard of the `info` command. I've always just used `cmd --help` and `man cmd`

Comment: Some people find `info` to be confusing to navigate because of the hyperlinking. If you dislike `info`, try piping it through less `info foo | less` to give you a familiar feel.

Comment: Goldentoa11, thanks for that.  Do feel free to accept the answer, by clicking on the tick outline next to it, if you're happy with it.

Comment: I install pinfo every now and then if I find myself needing to read INFO docs.  It gives lynx like navigation to info docs.

Comment: I really wish the GNU people would stop trying to make info happen.  Hardly anyone likes using it.

Comment: I agree, but they're writing the code, so they can do their doco any way they like.  It's not like we couldn't reformat it into an old-style `man` page if we were that upset about it.  `pinfo` looks nice, but it doesn't seem to know that `ls` info is in `coreutils` on my system (Fedora 19), even though `info` does.

Comment: Seriously, try `info foo | less`. It pipes everything through less, and functions very similarly to a manpage -- often the content is 99% identical. Once I found this I never looked back.

Answer (score 12):

As stated by @MadHatter this means the File/Directory has additional right trough Access Control Lists. Usually the Owner:Group system is enough, but in some cases you need a fainer grained permission control. There comes the acl system in touch.

To see the acls on a specific file/dir simply type:

```
getfacl myfileordir
```

For changing the permissions use the `setfacl` command. See in the man page of it, for the proper syntax.